# How to find and open index.php at XAMPP which crashes when mounting

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I was using fine `XAMPP` and `PHP` at my local server at `http://localhost:8080`  by writing and executing my source code in `index.php` which is located within `htdocs`. Then for some days, I started to run some things with `python` and `Flask` at `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`. Now that I want to run again some things with `XAMPP` and `PHP`, my MacBook crashes when I try to press the `Mount button` at the `Volumes window` at `XAMPP`:

[image]

After it restarts the Apple report is the following:

```
Anonymous UUID:       6078BFD9-71F8-915D-0AC3-8FC1A94D26BC

Wed May 23 15:11:36 2018

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8008388c2d): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f8b51b784, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffff8008c63f50, CR3: 0x00000002523d7037, CR4: 0x00000000003627e0
RAX: 0xffffff8008c63f40, RBX: 0xffffff801bfe0140, RCX: 0xffffff7f8b51b830, RDX: 0x0000000000000006
RSP: 0xffffff9127d1b770, RBP: 0xffffff9127d1b7a0, RSI: 0xffffff801aa2ac04, RDI: 0xffffff801bfe0150
R8:  0xffffff8008a9b7d0, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0xffffff8035fdde68, R11: 0x0000000000000000
R12: 0xffffff801aa2abf4, R13: 0xffffff801e611880, R14: 0xffffff801e6118a8, R15: 0xffffff801aa2ab20
RFL: 0x0000000000010283, RIP: 0xffffff7f8b51b784, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0xffffff8008c63f50, Error code: 0x0000000000000003, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 0, VF: 2

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff9127d1b220 : 0xffffff800826e166
0xffffff9127d1b270 : 0xffffff8008396714
0xffffff9127d1b2b0 : 0xffffff8008388a00
0xffffff9127d1b330 : 0xffffff8008220180
0xffffff9127d1b350 : 0xffffff800826dbdc
0xffffff9127d1b480 : 0xffffff800826d99c
0xffffff9127d1b4e0 : 0xffffff8008388c2d
0xffffff9127d1b660 : 0xffffff8008220180
0xffffff9127d1b680 : 0xffffff7f8b51b784
0xffffff9127d1b7a0 : 0xffffff7f8b51b292
0xffffff9127d1b7c0 : 0xffffff7f8b518b8d
0xffffff9127d1b800 : 0xffffff7f8b51a83e
0xffffff9127d1b840 : 0xffffff80086e9294
0xffffff9127d1b8a0 : 0xffffff80084a2e14
0xffffff9127d1b8f0 : 0xffffff80084c1812
0xffffff9127d1b980 : 0xffffff80084ac8bf
0xffffff9127d1bbc0 : 0xffffff80084ad304
0xffffff9127d1bf40 : 0xffffff8008804418
0xffffff9127d1bfa0 : 0xffffff8008220966
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.kaspersky.kext.klif(3.5.2a8)[C5C80763-4AD4-3655-8DD6-6DC659C92C83]@0xffffff7f8b517000->0xffffff7f8b534fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[F27A8A2A-6662-3608-83BD-415037509E01]@0xffffff7f88c46000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: mds

Mac OS version:
17E199

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.5.0: Mon Mar  5 22:24:32 PST 2018; root:xnu-4570.51.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1B55340B-0B14-3026-8A47-1E139DB63DA3
Kernel slide:     0x0000000008000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8008200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8008100000
System model name: MacBookPro12,1 (Mac-E43C1C25D4880AD6)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 2374279332239
last loaded kext at 256201909977: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs 1.10 (addr 0xffffff7f8b06d000, size 69632)
last unloaded kext at 390510274864: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10 (addr 0xffffff7f8b06d000, size 61440)
loaded kexts:
com.kaspersky.kext.mark.1.0.6   1.0.6
com.avast.PacketForwarder   2.1
com.kaspersky.nke   2.3.0a7
com.kaspersky.kext.klif 3.5.2a8
com.kaspersky.kext.kimul    46
com.avast.FileShield    4.0.0
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    6.2.1
com.apple.filesystems.exfat 1.4
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.18.48
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.18.48
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.5f3
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.5
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.33
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphics  10.3.2
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   281.51
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.12.6
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetooth20703USBTransport  6.0.5f3
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    211
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   6.01.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphicsFramebuffer   10.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 439.50.6
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.50.6
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.51.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329.50.2
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 133
com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC    1240.29.1a7
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   183
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.18.48
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 675.6
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   675.12
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 281.51
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    526
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.18.48
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   519.15
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.5f3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 281.51
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 281.51
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.18.48
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    378.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   211.12
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    519.15
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.40.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    1404.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   205
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 133
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.5f3
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  1404.4
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    1404.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    53
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.7.8
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  53
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.50.10
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.50.6
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140.50.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    675.12
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
Model: MacBookPro12,1, BootROM MBP121.0175.B00, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.7 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.28f7
Graphics: Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x4544464132333241324D412D4A442D460000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x4544464132333241324D412D4A442D460000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x133), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.37.29.1a7)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.5f3, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0128G, 121.33 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

The only major thing that I did to my laptop these days is to install `Kaspersky Antivirus`. I do not know if this has anything to do with my problem on `XAMPP` but there are multiple reports which mention something like this (https://forum.kaspersky.com/index.php?/topic/59468-xamppapache-not-working/,https://forum.kaspersky.com/index.php?/topic/304696-kaspersky-pure-3-xampp-modules-issue/, https://forum.kaspersky.com/index.php?/topic/198918-kaspersky-restricts-xampp/).

Perhaps, a good idea is to uninstall `XAMPP` and re-install it. But the problem is that in the `index.php` I had some source code which I have not saved elsewhere. Therefore, I have the impression that by uninstalling `XAMPP` and re-installing it this source code will be lost. Also, I do not know any other way to find and open the `index.php` but by pressing the `Mount button`; however this makes my laptop to crash for now.

A fact is that at `http://localhost:8080` an error is displayed exactly as it was displayed because of the source code in my `index.php` when I left this before some days which probably means that my source code in `index.php` is not lost.

**How can I find and open the `index.php` file in `htdocs` without pressing the `Mount button` at `XAMPP`?**

**Can I fix `XAMPP` so that it does not make my laptop to crash and retrieve the contents of `index.php`?**

P.S.
If I enter `/opt/lamp` at my files finder (Command + Shift + G) while `XAMPP` is running then it directs me here:

[image]

and I cannot find anything relevant to `index.php` and `htdocs` at first sight in it.

Comment: If XAMPP is crashing, try removing it and re-installing it. You can verify that it's not the index.php by moving it out of the directory and placing a simple index.php with just some text in it.

Comment: when you mount a volume you "transform" a folder (in this case /opt/lamp) in a volume to be used by xamp. Just use finder to navigate to /opt/lamp

Comment: Thanks @aynber for your comment. But if I uninstall then is the content of `index.php` going to be lost?

Comment: Thank you @LelioFaieta for your comment. I edited my post since I tried what you said but I could not find anything.

Comment: you cannot find anything because that is your root and not your /opt/lamp folder. Are you sure you didn't remove that folder for any reason?

Comment: I am pretty sure that I did not touch anything related to XAMPP. I simply started to code and run some things with Python.

Comment: Just copy out the file before you uninstall/delete XAMPP. Place it on the desktop or somewhere you can find it later.

Comment: By the way, the Kernel extension listed in your report is related to Kapersky Antivirus. Not sure where that would be coming into play.

Comment: @aynber: `Just copy out the file before you uninstall/delete XAMPP. Place it on the desktop or somewhere you can find it later`, for sure this is a good idea. But my question is exactly how to find the file if XAMPP crashes when I press the `Mount button`?

Comment: Yes, actually you are right, one thing that happened these days was that I installed Kaspersky Antivirus. Does this has to do with the fact that I cannot press the `Mount button` and instantly find `htdocs` and `index.php`?

Comment: The file never moves from htdocs. `/opt/lamp` is just a directory where XAMPP loads its system files for a virtual server.

Comment: Ok as I write at my post above I did that and I cannot find it. However, at `http://localhost:8080` an error of the source code in my `index.php` is shown exactly as it was shown when I left this before some days which probably means that my source code `index.php` is not lost. Therefore, if the `index.php` is not lost then how can I find it if I cannot do this by `/opt/lamp`?

Comment: You can search for `index.php` in Finder, or in Terminal do `sudo find / -name index.php`

Comment: Hmm, for now I can find some `index.php` files of some PHP programs I have saved on my pc but I cannot find the one of `htdocs`. The weird thing is that as I said you at `http://localhost:8080` I still get the error of my source code of `htdocs/index.php` but I cannot find the actual file for now!